# Find number of unordered pairs $(A,B)$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Find number of unordered pairs $(A,B)$ such that

$\bullet \space A$ and $B$ are subsets of an $n$ element set $S$

$\bullet \space A \cup B=S$

$\bullet \space A≠B$

Comment: @user84413-Question is quite unclear actually..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that the last two requirements together imply that $A,B$ are not both equal to $S,$ so by the first requirement at least one of them must be a *proper* subset of $S.$ Since order doesn't matter, then we may assume without loss of generality that $A\subsetneq S.$ How many such $A$ are there? Given such an $A,$ what must be the relationship between $B$ and $S\setminus A$? How many sets $B$ satisfy this property (this will vary with the cardinality of $A$)? What can we then conclude?

**Another Hint**: It is probably a good idea to explicitly figure this out for some specific $n$-element sets $S$ with $n$ small (like $n=0,1,2,3$) and see if you can get a feel for how things work at that level, then try to generalize (perhaps by induction).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $(X,Y,Z)$ be a partition of $S$.

Let $A=X\cup Y$, $B=Y\cup Z$

It can be checked that except the partition $(\phi,S,\phi)$, all other partitions satisfy all the conditions.

The answer should be obvious now.